# How to sort an multidimensional array using Php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array and want to sort in according to date and also want to get only 5 data from an array.

Array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [TITLE] => example1
            [DATE] => 2016-05-17
            [PST_BY] => 0
            [IMG_NM] => 
            [SLUG] => 
            [NAME] => Web Design & Development
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [TITLE] => example2
            [DATE] => 2016-05-20
            [PST_BY] => 0
            [IMG_NM] => 
            [SLUG] => 
            [NAME] => Mobile OS
        )
)
```

I am doing this but not working :

```
 $list = array_sort($blog, 'DATE', SORT_ASC);
 print_r($list);
```

Comment: _want to get only 5 data from an array._ What does it means?

Comment: There is [no `array_sort()`](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=array_sort) function in PHP?? Can you show us your function?

Comment: it means if i have 10 data then i want only 5 data with Date sorted.

Comment: Instead of `for each` or `for ($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++)` or whatever kinda loop you're using make sure you only iterate 5 times?

Comment: After you check out [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value) then use `$blog = array_splice($blog, 5);`

Comment: Use usort then supply your own call back

Comment: This is answered several time [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: @ManishTiwari I made solution for you, but cannot posted the answer because marked duplicate.. [CHECK THIS LINK](https://eval.in/574329)

Comment: Thanks @ManjeetBarnala...

Comment: @ManishTiwari work for you or not ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Example to sort on a specific key (in this case `name`):

```
// Function to compare two items in the array
function CompareName($left, $right) {
  return $left['name'] > $right['name'];
}

// Example array/data
$myarray = [
  ["id"=>1, "name"=>"foo"],
  ["id"=>2, "name"=>"bar"],
  ["id"=>3, "name"=>"ah"],
  ["id"=>4, "name"=>"zoo"]
];

echo 'Unsorted:';
var_dump($myarray);

usort($myarray , 'CompareName');

echo 'Sorted:';
var_dump($myarray);
```

> want to get only 5 data from an array

```
$top5 = array_slice($myarray, 0, 5);
```

or:

```
$top5 = array_splice($myarray, 0, 5);
```

Comment: I was thinking usort with a callback

Comment: usort / uasort; for this example both work. It depends on the actual requirements which OP wants to use. But the question is too vague...